# BlackBerry specific stylesheet

Tags: css, blackberry, stylesheet

We want to use the same page to service the desktop, iPhone, and BlackBerry, so we have to come up with a way for the different devices to load different stylesheets.

So, is there a way to specify a stylesheet to run on BlackBerry?

For example, iPhone's use the media attribute:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="style.css" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse the User Agent string using a server side language and serve the correct stylesheet. The blackberry seems to identify itself with "Blackberry/xyz". See e.g. [here](http://yabfog.com/blog/2006/12/11/blackberry-browser-user-agent)

Comment: Yeah, I was really hoping not to have to do it server side, but it's looking like that might be the only way.

Comment: Make sure you also look at the "profile" and/or "x-wap-profile" headers, because mobile browsers such as BlackBerry sometimes spoof the "user-agent" header to fool sites into thinking you're using Firefox or IE